# Wordpress two conditions (and if)

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm writing a sidebar for my site and I'm trying to check if:

1. The page is a post, via: `is_post()`
2. The author can edit the post via: `current_user_can('edit_post')`

I'm trying to combine both of these conditions, but I'm horrid at PHP and I just can't figure out the syntax to do so. I figured it'd be something like below. Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm assuming it's something simple, but my inexperience is causing problems and I can't find the right example/documentation to help me out.

> `<?php if is_single and if (current_user_can('edit_post')) { ?>
>   <li><a href="#">Edit post</a></li>
>   <?php ;} ?>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be:

```
<?php if (is_single() && current_user_can('edit_post')) { ?>
 <li><a href="#">Edit post</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! I knew it was a syntax problem. Learn something every day. Thanks again. I'll mark your answer as the solution as soon as it allows me to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax and idea is:

```
if (true && true) { 
   // things will happen ...
}
```

For your functions:

```
if (is_single() && current_user_can('edit_post')) { ...
```